# Tags on the Spacex fairing catchers

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There is currently a [mr-steven](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mr-steven) tag, for the Spacex vessel that catches fairings ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ms._Tree_(ship))).

This ship has since been renamed to Ms. Tree, and has a sister ship called Ms. Chief.

I believe it would be good to rename the tag to something like [fairing-recovery-vessel](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairing-recovery-vessel) and have [mr-steven](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mr-steven), [ms-tree](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-tree) and [ms-chief](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ms-chief) as synonyms.

Note that there is currently only one person with a score of more than 5, Bob Jacobsen, and maybe soon also BarrowWight with his recent answer. How are tags edited when there aren't enough users with enough score on them?

Comment: The tag rename is complete! I also added a brief tag excerpt mentioning the names of the two vessels, as well as the fact that Ms. Tree was formerly named Mr. Steven.

Comment: @called2voyage Should we maybe have synonyms like mr-steven, ms-tree and ms-chief?

Comment: I thought about it, but I think it's too early to say that they're necessary and we don't want to make it unnecessarily harder to make separate tags if the need arises. I suggest for now if someone tries to create one of those tags, we just retag the question, unless we suddenly get a huge flood of questions about the different vessels. If we find that we're retagging a lot, then we can revisit the issue here on meta.

Comment: If we do at some point have ms-tree and ms-chief subtags, I *do* think mr-steven should be a synonym of the ms-tree tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mods can intervene to do tag maintenance. There's only two questions on this tag, and both are about Mr. Steven (now Ms. Tree) specifically. I can see how renaming it [fairing-recovery-vessel](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairing-recovery-vessel) would allow more widespread adoption of the tag. I don't see sufficient justification to create sub-tags at this point. There's just not enough questions about each.

In any case, I do think it's clear the tag needs to be renamed. We'll give some time to see if people upvote my answer or if alternatives are proposed, and then we (the mods) can do whatever tag maintenance is needed.

Comment: The tireless efforts of our mods to cull, maintain and improve our vast array of tags is recognized and most appreciated!